# Getting Build error ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1 Help Please

Tags: selenium, asp.net-core, azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-pipelines

[Click here for yml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJdWD.png)

[Click here for azure log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfFxg.png)

Comment: Could you please show by text instead of screenshot? And from the screenshot it seems issue comes from the test step? Could you please add env variable 'system.debug' to true to get more details?

Comment: Tests are running fine as you can see it says Pass 3 and failed 0 so they are running its after the test run is finished is when I am getting that error

Comment: Can it be due to this Exception Exception System.TypeLoadException, Exception thrown executing tests Test Run Failed. @BowmanZhu-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the SDK 2.1.401 implicitly in the build pipeline.
[image]

Or

To explicitly set the version of SDK, edit the task "Use .NET Core sdk": just uncheck "Use global json" and a text box appears to enter the version of SDK needed

Comment: didn't work for me